# Two data outputs to be displayed on one 16x1 lcd display

Tags: display, data

Before pursuing this very far, I would like to know if I can get two different data outputs (one on the left 8 and the other data on the right 8).  And if so, are there any requirements on the display or any other thing that might be needed.  I'm thinking that as far as the proper Arduino platform being the Mega 2560.  My idea is to put together an FSX navigation radio for my flight simulator.

Comment: You can do anything you can write code for.

Comment: `lcd.setCursor(0,0); lcd.print("val1"); lcd.setCursor(8, 0); lcd.print("val2");`. Try reading the manual and examples.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalSetCursor

Comment: don't forget extra spaces on the right when drawing multiple numeric data: `lcd.print(String(v1,2) + "      ")` which allows negatives and more digits without leaving the previous draw's numbers behind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
lcd.setCursor(x, y);
```

To set the cursor.

Than you can output text with

```
lcd.print("Text");
```

Make sure you add spaces in case there is already text written to overwrite older text.

You can also use

```
lcd.clear();
```

to clear the display, but this might result in flickering if you do it too often.

Another possibility is to create a 16 character string

```
char lcdText[16];
```

and write characters in this string and set it at once with:

```
lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
lcd.print(lcdText);
```